# Can you use an iPad for Magento2 admin?

Tags: magento2, mobile, browser

Since there is no Flash on Magento2 can we use an iPad for Magento2 admin panel?

The [magento doc](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/system-requirements_browsers.html) is only showing browser support for storefront:

> - Safari Mobile for iPad 2, iPad Mini, iPad with Retina Display (iOS 7 or later), for desktop storefront
> - Safari Mobile for iPhone 4 or later; iOS 7 or later, for mobile storefront

If there is no Flash, why it doesn't support mobile browser for admin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Who said it doesn't?

The docs may not explicitly mention it, but yes, the M2 admin panel should work fine with iPads. I believe it was designed specifically with touch device UX in mind.